# When was the first ship model kit offered to the public?

Tags: ships

Following [this guy's question](https://modelshipworld.com/topic/12566-when-was-the-very-first-ship-model-kit-offered-to-the-public/) [requires login].

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_model) model ships are dated to ancient Greece, Egypt, and Phoenicia but those, and later models up to sometime in the 1800's, were all custom made by specialists.

According to [scalemates](https://www.scalemates.com/search.php?fkSECTION%5B%5D=Brands&q=*#) and the above article Amati was founded 1897 and Bassett-Lowke 1898 or 1899, both offering kits to the general public.

Scalemates has a list of 10,000 companies but it is hard to search and incomplete.

Comment: According to the database at [kartonmodellbau.org](https://www.kartonmodellbau.org/cgi-bin/bogen.pl), French printer [J. F. Wentzel](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Fr%C3%A9d%C3%A9ric_Wentzel) was offering a [cardboard sheet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardboard_modeling) for building a steam ship in 1861, and one for a Chinese ship (hull) in 1862.